# Why the measurement is different than the object properties?

Tags: units, measurement, settings

Default scene, my units are set to meters and default cube is 1 cubic unit obviously, but when I measure it it's actually 2 meters cube not 1.

The measurement tool is basically showing me double than in the object properties.

[image]

Comment: "*Default cube is 1 cubic unit obviously*" Are you sure of that?

Comment: Yeah ? It's 1x1x1 ? Units are set to meters so its suppose to be 1 cubic meter ? It is 1 cubic unit for sure and since the units are set to METERS it should be a CUBIC METER ... ? Why not ? I mean it makes perfect sense to me ...

Comment: Apparently the DIMENSIONS are different than the SCALE and they are in the side menu that opens up with N ...

Comment: The scale defines what the "normal" size of an object is, dimensions are measurements in world space. If you model a car 4.63 m long on the Y axis, that it a dimension of 4.63 m at a scale of 1. Scaling down to 10% of it's original size is a scale of 0.1 and a dimension of 0.463 m. The default cube at scale (1, 1, 1) is 2 m × 2 m × 2 m, because the cube and the other mesh primitives are created based on a unit sphere, which has a **radius** of 1 m, centered at (0, 0, 0). Therefore all primitive objects go from -1 to 1 on each axis at their base scale (if not unevenly shaped like the monkey).

Comment: By the way, the scale which you marked in your screenshot is in a section titled Transform, it is not saying that these are the dimensions. This area shows the transforms which are applied to an object in _Object Mode_, i.e. the changes made to the location, rotation and scale.